# Java gson convert error

Tags: java, json, swing, gson, netbeans-platform

İ'm trying to develop swing app on netbeans.İ'm using gson to decode json.İ get json data from php site. İ couldn't convert json data to java array.

How could i convert getting json file to java array. And then İ need to set jcombobox datasource this array.

My json file like this on url

```
[{"id":"1",
"ad":"jack",
"latitude":"41.0000",
"longitude":"32.000",
"speed":"",
"hour":"01:28:56",
"day":"18.04.2016",
"adres":"adres",
"resimyol":"http:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?.jpg"},
{"id":"2",
"ad":"Abraham",
"latitude":"41.0000",
"longitude":"41.0000",
"speed":"",
"hour":"01:28:56",
"day":"18.04.2016",
"adres":"adres",
"resimyol":"http:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?.jpg"}]
```

And here my java file

```
public class JsonPojo {
public String id;
public String ad;
public String latitude;
public String longitude;
public String speed;
public String hour;
public String day;
public String adres;
public String resimyol;
public String getId() { return id; }
public String getName() { return ad; }
public String getlat() { return latitude; }
public String getlon() { return longitude; }
public String getspeed() { return speed; }
public String gethour() { return hour; }
public String getday() { return day; }
public String getadres() { return adres; }
public String getresim() { return resimyol; }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
public void run() {
            new KonumGoster().setVisible(true);
             String json = null;
            try {
                json = readUrl("http://url.com/"
                        + "json.php");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(KonumGoster.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

Gson gson = new Gson();    
JsonPojo[] array = gson.fromJson(gson, JsonPojo[].class); 
JsonPojo obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonPojo.class);
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getId());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getName());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getlat());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getlon());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getspeed());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.gethour());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getday());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getadres());
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getresim());

}
```

When am i trying to run project its give me error like this

`run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 13 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
    at KonumGoster$1.run(KonumGoster.java:145)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 13 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
    ... 19 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 minutes 5 seconds)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
JsonPojo[] array = gson.fromJson(gson, JsonPojo[].class); 
JsonPojo obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonPojo.class);
```

The second statement uses `gson` instead of `json` as the first argument of Gson::fromJson. If you change this to `json`, GSON will do its job correctly.

And the error message in your build comes from the third statement, where you are trying to read a single oject out of a JSON array of objects. You only need the second statement and then iterate over its result to print each item.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonPojo[] array = gson.fromJson(json, JsonPojo[].class);
for (JsonPojo obj : array) {
    System.out.println("id: " + obj.getId());
    // etc
}
```